# My jQuery ajax if/else on click is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I've been stuck at this problem for quite a long time. Basically I have a button (#action) located in index.html. I have a second page : number.html. I'm trying to get in the .receiver span from index.html either .success content or .failure content from number.html, depending if #action was clicked in less than 2 seconds.

Here is the code :

```
$(function() {

    var ajaxRetrieve = function(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'number.html',
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(responseData) {
                callback(responseData);
            },
            error: function(responseData) {
                alert('Check yourself');
            }
        });
    }

    var flag = 0;

    $('#action').on('click', function() {
        flag = 1;
    });

    if (flag == 1) {
        ajaxRetrieve(function(data) {
            $('.receiver').html($(data).find('.success'));
        });
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            ajaxRetrieve(function(data) {
                $('.receiver').html($(data).find('.failure'));
            });
        }, 3000);
    };


});
```

Problem : on click, I never get the .success content, and I have no error message. But after 2 seconds, the .failure actually shows up. I tried several ways to make it work but it doesnt. I also checked if the flag value was changed on click with an alert box, and it was

Comment: your code will run always even though you did not click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the ajax calls within the `on click` function, otherwise the `if` logic will only be called when the page is loaded and never again.

```
$(function() {

    var ajaxRetrieve = function(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'number.html',
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(responseData) {
                callback(responseData);
            },
            error: function(responseData) {
                alert('Check yourself');
            }
        });
    }

    var flag = 0;

    $('#action').on('click', function() {
        flag = 1;
        flagCheck();
    });

    var flagCheck = function() {
        if (flag == 1) {
            ajaxRetrieve(function(data) {
                $('.receiver').html($(data).find('.success'));
            });
        } else {
            setTimeout(function() {
                ajaxRetrieve(function(data) {
                    $('.receiver').html($(data).find('.failure'));
                });
            }, 3000);
        };
    }

});
```